# Knowing source of a call in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Is there a way of know where a call originated from on a BlackBerry handset programatically?

for instance whether it was a call log entry, or a phonebook entry or a dial pad entry?

I just want to know if i can change my app in such a way that it would have knowledge of where and when a call originated.

Answer (score 0):

I am very much sure that it is practically not possible in blackberry. you can only listen to calls but not the source of call.